# Probablity of there being 3 or more red marbles after picking 7 marbles from a bag containing 100 marbles of which 24 are red

Tags: probability

What is the probability of there being $3$ or more red marbles after picking $7$ marbles from a bag containing $100$ marbles of which $24$ are red?

My head is in a spin trying to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Take it one step at a time.  Do you know how to answer the question of what is the probability of selecting **exactly** three red marbles when drawing seven from your bag?  The [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is useful here.

Comment: From the wiki page: "The hypergeometric distribution is a discrete probability distribution that describes the probability of $k$ successes (random draws for which the object drawn has a specified feature)(*in this case 3 red marbles*) in $n$ draws (*in this case 7 marbles*), without replacement, from a finite population of size N (*in this case 100 marbles*) that contains exactly $K$ objects with that feature (*in this case 24 red marbles*), wherein each draw is either a success or a failure."  The page goes on to tell you the exact formula it follows.

Answer (score 1):

The probability for selecting $k$ from $24$ red marbles and $7-k$ from $76$ non-red, when selecting $7$ from $100$ is (*what?*): $$\mathsf P(R=k)= \ldots$$
Now you seek the probability for selecting *at least* $3$ from $24$ red marbles.   The complement is *less than* $3$, the probability of which is easier to sum up.

$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(R\geq 3) &= 1-\mathsf P(R<3)\\ &=1-\sum_{k=0}^2\mathsf P(R=k)\end{split}$$

Comment: Hi Graham & JM, thanks sirs but what would the answer be?

Comment: @IanG you'll have to show that you've put in a bit more effort in attempting to fully understand what hints we've already given before you get a numerical answer from me at least.  I gave you a link to the wikipedia page on [hypergeometric distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) and that topic should also be covered in any introductory textbook on the subject.  Have you looked over that page or read about them yet?  What have you learned that they are useful for?  Do you see why they are useful for your specific scenario?  Do you see how to use it?

Comment: Thanks Sir, my numerical answer is 0.16 for the probability of exactly 3 using the hypergeometric info from Wikipedia, now I suppose I just have to work out the probabilities for 4 to 7 and add them, but is there a shorter way?

Comment: The probability that exactly three of the marbles picked were red is *approximately* $0.16$.  Whenever you can be *exact* rather than use *approximate* values, the better, especially when you have calculators available.  If you don't but want to be exact anyways, leave it in a form using binomial coefficients and don't bother to simplify.  `Is there a shorter way?` Yes, as pointed out already by GrahamKemp above, rather than doing $Pr(R\geq 3)=Pr(R=3)+Pr(R=4)+Pr(R=5)+Pr(R=6)+Pr(R=7)$, it is a bit less work to do instead $Pr(R\geq 3) = 1-Pr(R=2)-Pr(R=1)-Pr(R=0)$.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen